# React-scripts permission denied

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing this issue when i start my project with npm start error is

```
Sh: line1:/run/media/admin/LocalDiskD/react-practice/test-app/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied
```

I am using linux operating system

Comment: Then change the permissions to e**x**ecutable: `chmod +x /run/media/admin/LocalDiskD/react-practice/test-app/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts`. This does not look like your typical projects folder, however. What environment are you running this in?

Comment: No idea about environment